# Leaving a Computer Science Ph.D. program for Google after getting a M.S

Tags: phd, industry, quitting

This age old question has probably been asked, but there are always new considerations and specifics. Also I want to hear from people who have quit the program themselves, namely the biggest question of all: Do you regret it? and, did you ever feel that it hurt you later in your industry life? (assuming you have a Masters)

I have a fellowship and I'm in a prestigious program, but I am truly suffering in it. My advisor puts us (the students) against each other to compete and there are tons of politics. Of course industry is not without politics, but I have had experiences there and it was not this bad.

My current options are to switch advisors and start the research portion from scratch or accept a nice offer from Google for a very interesting team that is similar to my line of research. In the short term, I know I will enjoy being in a company. I'm a bit older (32) and I've worked in companies before. I also have friends there and I miss working in a collaborative team. I'm afraid however, in the long term certain positions or opportunities will be closed off for me. And of course a general feel of feel failure.

Comment: If you want to give industry a try, take a leave of absence -- don't burn your bridges!

Comment: I was in similar situation long time ago (the only difference is that Google did not exist back then). I think it's very unlikely you'll come back to Academia once you leave for industry. My advice is to **figure out what and where your mind and your heart are** before you make the decision.  What do you truly want to do (in your heart)? What do you think you should do (in your mind)? To answer your question: _Do you regret it_? Yes, I do. Please see [this answer](http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/14274/546).